# How to save pdf from binary code with VUEJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pdf, binary

Am sending a request via axios to get a pdf file, The problem am receiving the pdf file as a binary code :

```
"%PDF-1.4\n%????\n2 0 obj\n<<\/Filter\/FlateDecode\/Length 2100>>stream\nx??....."
```

I was trying hard to save the file but the file was saved as an empty pdf. What is the problem with my code please.

Note please i saw few post related to such an issue but non of them works.
My code:

```
axios.get(process.env.VUE_APP_PUBLIC_API + '/preview-my-bill?id=123456',
          {
            responseType: 'blob',
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/pdf',
              'content-type': 'application/pdf',
              'content-transfer-encoding': 'binary',
              'content-disposition': 'attachment; filename=invoice_35206159.pdf'
            }
          }
      ).then(res => {
        var blob = new Blob([res.data], {type: "application/pdf"});
        var downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
        downloadLink.target = '_blank';
        downloadLink.download = 'test.pdf';
        const downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        this.PreviewInvoice = downloadUrl;
        downloadLink.href = downloadUrl;
        document.body.append(downloadLink);
        downloadLink.click();
        document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
        URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl);
        console.log(blob)
        console.log(downloadUrl)
      })
```

My response is like this:

```
{
     data: "Blob {size: 43985, type: 'application/json'}"
    "status": 200,
    "statusText": "OK",
    "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        "link": "<http://mydomain.local/api/>; rel=\"https://api.w.org/\""
    },
    "config": {
        "transformRequest": {},
        "transformResponse": {},
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1,
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/pdf",
            "content-transfer-encoding": "binary",
            "content-disposition": "attachment; filename=invoice_35206159.pdf"
        },
        "method": "get",
        "responseType": "blob",
  
    },
    "request": {}
}
```